# Match & index to lookup data from multiple worksheets and summarize on one worhsheet

Tags: vba, excel, lookup

I have daily stock data for about two years.

The stock data is in 556 files but is arranged in the same way (note that about 5 additional stocks have been listed over this period). I want to summarize the movements in stock prices on one worksheet by picking them from the 556 files using match and index with my list of stock codes (named "MatchRange"). I've put the file names of the 556 files on row 2 of the summary worksheet.

I've used the code below but isn't working as it should. It just opens the files and closes them. Does anyone have any tips on how I can improve the code?

```
Sub NSEMerger()

Dim SummarySheet As Worksheet
Dim FolderPath As String
Dim i As Long
Dim n As Long
Dim c As Long
Dim FileName As String
Dim WorkBk As Workbook
Dim MatchRange As Range
Dim LookupRange As Range
Dim IndexRange As Range

'Define where data is being copied to, source folder and counter
Set SummarySheet = ActiveSheet
FolderPath = "C:\Users\lxxxx\Desktop\NSE Attachments\"
i = 1

'Define the size of the match range
n = Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(Range("MatchRange"))

' Call Dir the first time, pointing it to all Excel files in the folder path.
FileName = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xl*")


' Loop for all file names along the top row
Do While FileName = Range("A2").Offset(0, i).Value & ".xls"

    ' Open a workbook in the folder and define lookup range for match function and index range
    Set WorkBk = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & FileName)
    Set LookupRange = WorkBk.Worksheets(1).Range("H:H")
    Set IndexRange = WorkBk.Worksheets(1).Range("D:D")

    ' Open workbook and do match index
    For c = 1 To n Step 1

    SummarySheet.Range("MatchRange")(c).Offset(0, i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(IndexRange, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(SummarySheet.Range("MatchRange")(c), LookupRange, 0))

    Next

    ' Close the source workbook without saving changes.
    WorkBk.Close savechanges:=False

    ' Increase i to move to next data
    i = i + 1

    ' Use Dir to get the next file name.
    FileName = Dir()
Loop   
End Sub
```

Comment: What means "it doesn't seem to be working"? Try some debugging. The concatenation `FolderPath & "*.xl*"` will lead to "C:\Users\lxxxx\Desktop\NSE Attachments*.xl*". Looks wrong? So try `FolderPath = "C:\Users\lxxxx\Desktop\NSE Attachments\"`.

Comment: Thanks Axel. I mean that it's not working. Adding the "\" after the folder path now opens the files but the match index part is not working. I think that it has to do with the SummarySheet reference.

Comment: Inside the `.Match(SummarySheet.Range("MatchRange")(c)` function you've got `(c)` - what is this supposed to be?

Comment: The match range is an array of cells. The c refers to the "cth" cell within the range.

Comment: Does that work? Separate the `Match` and the `Index` functions into separate lines, storing the `Match` result in a variable which then gets used by the `Index` function. Then check which part is failing. Or am I focusing on wrong piece of code?

Comment: I've tried that bit of code on its own and it seems to work fine. I'm convinced the problem is on Set SummarySheet = ActiveSheet.

Comment: That line of code will be fine if you are looking at the summary sheet when you run the code. Maybe you'd better explain how the code isn't working. If you change   `SummarySheet.Range("MatchRange")(c).Offset(0, i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(IndexRange, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(SummarySheet.Range("MatchRange")(c), LookupRange, 0))`   to   `SummarySheet.Range("MatchRange")(c).Offset(0, i).Value = "test " & c`    Does it write to the expected place?

Comment: @ChipsLetten, I've made the change you suggested. It doesn't write anything to the expected place.

Comment: Your code is mixing up how it finds the file names. Should it be using the `Dir` function or should it be reading the names from the top row of summary sheet?

Comment: @ChipsLetten, the code works when matching numeric data. The problem seems to be when the range to be matched contains a mix of numeric and non-numeric characters. Any reason why this may be the case?

Comment: So the match fails when `...Match(SummarySheet.Range("MatchRange")(c)` is non-numeric? Do you consistently have upper case or lower case in your data? Does trying the `INDEX` & `MATCH` functions manually in the worksheets work?   Have you changed the code in response to my earlier comment about how it finds the file names? Might be worth posting a new question.